# Right join and where condition Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display only the time available, to achieve that I'm trying to do this query

```
select * from agenda  right join tbl_hora on agenda.hora_id = tbl_hora.id_hor where  agenda.hora_id is null and  medico_id = 40 and evento_inicio = '2012-05-05';
```

However, it retrieves me 0 rows if I remove the where conditions from medico_id and evento_inicio, it display all the rows, how could I make the query to display the available time.

P.D. the agenda table is empty, because is an ajax call to make and appointment.

Answer (score 0):

> from agenda  right join tbl_hora on agenda.hora_id = tbl_hora.id_hora

this means select from agenda table **only** the rows that it's hora_id column has a match in the `tbl_hora` and all rows from tbl_hora table

> where  agenda.hora_id is null

and select from the result after joining  **only** the rows that it's `agenda.hora_id` is null.

which means **you will always get 0 results** unless there is a row in  agenda that it's `.hora_id` column  is null and **also** a row in tbl_hora that it's `.id` column  is null too

you need to remove the `where  agenda.hora_id is null` and use the condition you search for instead

Comment: if I remove the agenda.hora_id  is null condition, then my result is going to be 0 because my agenda table is empty. How could be a better way to choose the result that not is not in both tables.

Comment: @Paul can you provide a sample from agenda table and tbl_hora table data . because what you say " because my agenda table is empty" means right join while agenda is on the left side will never bring results!

Comment: I use this query to resolve, what do you think about it ?                                 `select * from tbl_hora where not exists (select hora_id from agenda where agenda.hora_id = tbl_hora.id_hor and medico_id = 40 and evento_inicio=  '2012-01-07');`